Unmet dependencies installing ros-jazzy-desktop on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, kernel 6.9.1
Steps to reproduce issue:
Follow steps from https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debs.html
Expected behavior:
Install OK
Actual behavior:
sudo apt install ros-jazzy-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libbz2-dev : Depends: libbz2-1.0 (= 1.0.8-5.1) but 1.0.8-5.1build0.1 is to be installed
Recommends: bzip2-doc but it is not going to be installed
libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl4t64 (= 8.5.0-2ubuntu10) but 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3 is to be installed
liblz4-dev : Depends: liblz4-1 (= 1.9.4-1build1) but 1.9.4-1build1.1 is to be installed
libtiff-dev : Depends: liblzma-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libtiff6 (= 4.5.1+git230720-4ubuntu2) but 4.5.1+git230720-4ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
Depends: libdeflate-dev but it is not going to be installed
libzstd-dev : Depends: libzstd1 (= 1.5.5+dfsg2-2build1) but 1.5.5+dfsg2-2build1.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Also tried from https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Install-Binary.html, same sort of problem different libs:
rosdep install --from-paths ~/ros2_jazzy/ros2-linux/share --ignore-src -y --skip-keys "cyclonedds fastcdr fastrtps iceoryx_binding_c rmw_connextdds rti-connext-dds-6.0.1 urdfdom_headers"
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libtiff-dev : Depends: liblzma-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libzstd-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libtiff6 (= 4.5.1+git230720-4ubuntu2) but 4.5.1+git230720-4ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
Depends: libdeflate-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y libopencv-dev] failed


Turns out since my last dist-upgrade I didn't have the updates and security Ubuntu repos in sources.list, so had about a gig of missing stuff! Looks like my original sources.list got renamed to sources.list.distUpgrade during the upgrade and the new one just had the normal repo (no updates and no security).
After adding those, installation ran without any issues.
